# Add "disabled" attribute to Bootstrap button via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal dialog and one of the buttons calls a script that makes an AJAX request. I need to add the disabled="disabled" attribute to the button that makes the call if the AJAX response is successful.

Here's my modal dialog:

```html
<div class="modal" id="contact1CallModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Call Contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Calling John Citizen</p>
      </div>
      <div id="ajaxError1" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
        Error Response
      </div>
      <div id="ajaxSuccess1" class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
        Success Response
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="callContact1" class="btn btn-success">Start Call</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

and here's the script that runs when the Start Call button is clicked:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  console.log('starting call back request');
  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $callBackURL ;?>" + defaultCallBackNumber + "<?php echo $contact1CallBack ;?>",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
      var httpStatus = status;
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
      console.log('httpResponseText: ' + httpResponseText);
      $('#ajaxSuccess1').html('Call in Progress').show();
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
      var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + ' ' + httpResponseText;
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
      console.log('httpResponseText: ' + httpResponseText);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxError1').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

Not sure how to add a line that adds the disabled="disabled" elements to the Start Call button?

Comment: you only need to do $("#callContact1").prop('disabled', true); when your ajax request return the result

Comment: Are you sure all other ajax functions are working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ajax response is successful, execute this code.

```
$( "#callContact1" ).prop( "disabled", true );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line in the then function if the call is success

```
.then(function(data, status, xhr) {
      $("#callContact1").prop( "disabled", true );
      var httpStatus = status;
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
      console.log('httpResponseText: ' + httpResponseText);
      $('#ajaxSuccess1').html('Call in Progress').show();
    })
```

If you want to add it as soon as the button is clicked, add this as the first line of click function

```
$("#callContact1").prop( "disabled", true );
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You should not use `attr` to set disabled, but `prop` as mentioned by @JVLobo and as stated in the jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc-1

Comment: tahnks for correcting me @DanielBernsons .. updated code with prop